# c++ trouble with making a bitmap from scratch

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

I am trying to make a bitmap from scratch. I have a `BYTE` array (with known size)  of RGB values and I would like to generate an HBITMAP.

For further clarification, the array of bytes I am working with is purely RGB values.

I have made sure that all variables are set and proper, and I believe that the issue has to do with `lpvBits`. I have been doing as much research for this in the past few days I have been unable to find anything that makes sense to me.

For testing purposes the `width = 6` and `height = 1`

Code:

```
HBITMAP RayTracing::getBitmap(void){
    BYTE * bytes = getPixels();
    void * lpvBits = (void *)bytes;
    HBITMAP hBMP = CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, 24, lpvBits);
    return hBMP;
}
BYTE * RayTracing::getPixels(void){
    Vec3 * vecs = display.getPixels();
    BYTE * bytes;
    bytes = new BYTE[(3 * width * height)];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (width * height); i++){
        *bytes = static_cast<BYTE>(vecs->x);
        bytes++;
        *bytes = static_cast<BYTE>(vecs->y);
        bytes++;
        *bytes = static_cast<BYTE>(vecs->z);
        bytes++;
        vecs++;
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: so what do you expect to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: I am trying to display the HBITMAP, but there is nothing showing up and no error.

Comment: Did you word-align the scan-lines? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183485(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Deduplicator I am having difficulty understanding what it means to word align my raw pixels

Comment: @MichaelMitchell: the allocated space for each line of pixels must be an even multiple of 2 bytes. You are creating a 24bit bitmap. Lets say `width` were 1. Each scan line would require 3 bytes of pixel data and 1 pad byte, so you have to allocate `(3+1)*height` bytes for the array. If `width` were 2, each scan line would require 6 bytes, which is aligned, so the array would require `6*height` bytes, and so on.  When allocating the array, multiply `width` by `bits/8` and round to the next highest multiple of 2, and make sure to account for that padding when filling the array with pixels

Comment: @RemyLebeau so I could loop through lines of my pixels and add additional bytes (if needed) between that line and the next?

Comment: Lack of word-alignment would not result in "nothing showing up", so I suspect this isn't your (only) problem. Perhaps you should post some more code as you may have more fundamental things wrong.

Comment: @MichaelMitchell: yes, you have to add the extra bytes when allocating the array, and skip the extra bytes when looping through the array.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I have added some more code.

Comment: @MichaelMitchell: the documentation being linked to is misleading. Scanlines are actually dword aligned, must be even multiples of 4 bytes, not 2. So, when width is 6, each scanline has 2 pad bytes (`((3*6)+2) = 20`), but your code is not allocating those bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly dword-align your array so each line is an even multiple of 4 bytes, and then skip those bytes when filling the array:

```
HBITMAP RayTracing::getBitmap(void)
{
    BYTE * bytes = getPixels();
    HBITMAP hBMP = CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, 24, bytes);
    delete[] bytes;
    return hBMP;
}

BYTE * RayTracing::getPixels(void)
{
    Vec3 * vecs = display.getPixels(); // <-- don't forget to free if needed
    int linesize = ((3 * width) + 3) & ~3; // <- 24bit pixels, width number of pixels, rounded to nearest dword boundary
    BYTE * bytes = new BYTE[linesize * height];
    for (unsigned int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        BYTE *line = &bytes[linesize*y];
        Vec3 *vec = &vecs[width*y];
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            *line++ = static_cast<BYTE>(vec->x);
            *line++ = static_cast<BYTE>(vec->y);
            *line++ = static_cast<BYTE>(vec->z);
            ++vec;
        }
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The third parameter of CreateBitmap should be 3, not 1. There are three color planes: Red, Green, and Blue.

Also, if you set the height to anything greater than one, you'll need to pad each row of pixels with zeroes to make the width a multiple of 4. So for a 6x2 image, after saving the 6*3 bytes for the first row, you'd need to save two zero bytes to make the row 20 bytes long.

Comment: I am not to sure about that. I believe it should still be one. Also, I get a run time error if I change it to 3 instead of 1.

Comment: I checked Google, and it looks like CreateBitmap is a really old function that should really only be used for monochrome bitmaps. Use CreateDIBSection instead.

Comment: 1 is the correct value - check the docs for `BITMAPINFOHEADER` ("The number of planes for the target device. This value must be set to 1.")

Comment: The width of each scan line needs to be aligned, even if height is 1.

Comment: Don't check Google, check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183485.aspx). It is not simply that CreateBitmap is too old to create color bitmaps, it's that color matching is hard. CreateCompatibleBitmap and CreateDIBSection make it slightly easier.